# Is there a term for the operation of multiplying the product of two matrices by the transpose of the first matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Is there a term for the operation $A B A^T$? In colloquial terms, I might call this a "sandwich" of a matrix between another matrix and the transpose of that other matrix.

How about for the special case where $B$ (as well as $A B A^T$) is symmetric?  This shows up often in Kalman filtering.

I would like to look up some properties of this kind of operation but I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: If $B$ is the matrix of a bilinear form then this is just a change of basis.

Comment: The term is "similarity transformation". A and B are called similar if $B=XAX^T$.  When we have a quadratic form represented by A in the standard basis, then B represents the same form in a new basis.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I thought that a similarity required $X$ to be invertible? Otherwise this isn't an equivalence relation.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: you are right. If $X$ is not invertible, I do not know a name for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B=XAX^T$ classically one says that A and B are congruent.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite to $\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{X}^T$ there is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3367651)

Names for the product will depend on the properties of $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{A}$